# Commits added to both feature branch and master

Tags: git

I have a feature branch feat123. I needed to take changes from master. Hence I did `git co feat123` and `git merge master`.
That went fine and after that I introduced two new commits on my feat123 branch. At this stage `git diff --name-only master...` showed that I changed around 30 files on my branch. `git log` showed merge commit and some other previous commits.

Then on my branch I could see new commit that was supposed to be done on master, well it seems like it ended up on both master and my branch. I verified that usgin `gitk` and `git log`.
The same thing happen with more commits and now `git diff` shows that I modified 80 files, on my feat123 branch, including those that I have never touched while working on this branch. Again using `gitk` and `git log` I can see those commits present both on master and feat123. They have different SHA1 but the same content. Like there were cherry-picked but I did not do that.

I don't know happened. Can someone please explain me what could go wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but your question isn't very clear. What did you do just before the "wrong" commits appeared? And what command are you running that makes you think they're "on both branches"?

Comment: @IMSoP. I edited the question slightly.  Just before those wrong commits appeared I did two small commits on this branch, but everything looked perfectly ok after those commits made by me.

Comment: I'm still having trouble picturing the sequence of events here. Commits don't appear from nowhere, there must have been _some_ command in between "everything looked perfectly ok" and "I could see new commits that were supposed to be done on master". Did you maybe run "git pull"? Or are you saying that you _created_ those extra commits, but you thought you'd created them on "master"?